# Unable to update entities via spring repository

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-boot, spring-data-rest

Here is my code. I'm changing

```
@RequestMapping(value={"/set_channels"}, method={RequestMethod.POST})
public void setChannels(@RequestParam(value = "fromIndex") int fromIndex,
                        @RequestParam(value = "toIndex") int toIndex,
                        @RequestBody Channel channel) {
    List<Channel> allChannels = repository.findAllByOrderByBinIndexAsc();
    if (allChannels.isEmpty()) {
        createChannels(fromIndex, toIndex, channel);
    }
    else {
        updateAndOrCreateChannels(allChannels, fromIndex, toIndex, channel);
    }
}

private void updateAndOrCreateChannels(List<Channel> allChannels, int fromIndex, int toIndex, Channel channel) {

    int minBinIndex = allChannels.get(0).getBinIndex();
    int maxBinIndex = allChannels.get(allChannels.size() - 1).getBinIndex();

    for (Channel ch: allChannels) {
        if (ch.getBinIndex() >= fromIndex && ch.getBinIndex() <= toIndex) {
            channel.copySettings(channel);
        }
    }
    // error here!!!
    repository.save(allChannels);
    if (fromIndex < minBinIndex || toIndex > maxBinIndex) {
        List<Channel> newChannels = new ArrayList<>(minBinIndex - fromIndex + toIndex - maxBinIndex);
        for (int i = fromIndex; i < minBinIndex; i ++) {
            newChannels.add(new Channel(channel, i));
        }
        for (int i = maxBinIndex + 1; i <= fromIndex; i++) {
            newChannels.add(new Channel(channel, i));
        }
        repository.save(newChannels);
    }
}
```

Here is my channel entity.

```
package demo.model.processing;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

/**
 * Created by michael on 21/08/15.
 */
@Entity
public class Channel {

    @NotNull
    private ChannelMode mode;
    @NotNull
    private boolean excluded;
    @NotNull
    private double manualCoefficient;
    @NotNull
    private double c1;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Channel{" +
                ", mode=" + mode +
                ", excluded=" + excluded +
                ", manualCoefficient=" + manualCoefficient +
                ", c1=" + c1 +
                ", c2=" + c2 +
                ", binIndex=" + binIndex +
                '}';
    }

    @NotNull
    private double c2;
    @Id
    private int binIndex;

    public void copySettings(Channel other) {
        setMode(other.getMode());
        setC1(other.getC1());
        setC2(other.getC2());
        setManualCoefficient(other.getManualCoefficient());
        setExcluded(other.isExcluded());
    }

    public Channel() {}

    public Channel(ChannelMode mode,
                   double c2,
                   double c1,
                   double manualCoefficient,
                   boolean excluded,
                   int binIndex) {
        setMode(mode);
        setC2(c2);
        setC1(c1);
        setManualCoefficient(manualCoefficient);
        setExcluded(excluded);
        setBinIndex(binIndex);
    }
```

Here is my Channel Entity. As you can see I'm trying to use binIndex as Id.

```
    public Channel(Channel other, int newBinIndex) {
        setMode(other.getMode());
        setC1(other.getC1());
        setC2(other.getC2());
        setManualCoefficient(other.getManualCoefficient());
        setExcluded(other.isExcluded());
        setBinIndex(newBinIndex);
    }

    public ChannelMode getMode() {

        return mode;
    }

    public void setMode(ChannelMode mode) {
        this.mode = mode;
    }

    public boolean isExcluded() {
        return excluded;
    }

    public void setExcluded(boolean excluded) {
        this.excluded = excluded;
    }

    public double getManualCoefficient() {
        return manualCoefficient;
    }

    public void setManualCoefficient(double manualCoefficient) {
        this.manualCoefficient = manualCoefficient;
    }

    public double getC1() {
        return c1;
    }

    public void setC1(double c1) {
        this.c1 = c1;
    }

    public double getC2() {
        return c2;
    }

    public void setC2(double c2) {
        this.c2 = c2;
    }

    public int getBinIndex() {
        return binIndex;
    }

    public void setBinIndex(int binIndex) {
        this.binIndex = binIndex;
    }
}
```

And this gives me the error.

```
DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint ["PRIMARY KEY ON PUBLIC.CHANNEL(BIN_INDEX)"; SQL statement:
insert into channel (c1, c2, excluded, manual_coefficient, mode, bin_index) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) [23505-187]]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception
```

Well repository trying to insert instead of update then this message is not surprise, but why insert in the first place. I haven't changed the id.

EDIT1

The idea behind this channel is that there is a fix number of this channels in the system. They unique by binIndex. And this binIndex is a always a number from 0 to n. So if we have 10 channels they would have bin indices 0..10. And after they have been created we only need to update them.

This request is about "Create or update existing channels with binIndices from x to y and with settings like in this example channel".

Comment: This `channel.copySettings(channel);` isn't going to do much... Copying to itself? Also imho what you do should be in a single transactional service method, in your case you get multiple transactions and thus detached entities. Also your id is the element number in the collection, not sure if that is the smartest way to determine an id....

Comment: copySettings doing exactly what it should, it's copying settings from one channel to another while retaining binIndex.

Comment: @M.Deinum I don't care about transaction in this case, I won't have any performance issues.

Comment: @M.Deinum Also about multiple transactions, you mean I'm getting 3 transaction? Or you think that when saving list of entities I'm saving each in its own transaction?

Comment: You are getting multiple transactions for each call to save and that will be a performance hit, next to that a functional issue what if it partially fails, what are you going to do. The line I mentioned doesn't do anything, it copies from `channel` to `channel`. Check the line (or you haven't placed to code as you are using) I mentioned. You probably want `ch.copySettings(channel)`.